# Relationship between 4SID and 4DVAR

Tags: estimation, kalman-filter, optimal

**Background:**
The "4SID" method allows one to back analytic models from data using a form similar to that of a Kalman filter. ([1](http://www.trnka.name/download/subspace/ThesisProposal.pdf))

The 4DVAR is an approach to use data with an analytic model for weather forecasting that is also an extension of the Kalman filter. ([2](http://www.weatherchaos.umd.edu/papers/Old_fourdvar_2.pdf))

The ensemble Kalman filter (EnKF) is also used to combine model and data for weather forecasting and is also a variation on the Kalman filter 3

**Questions:**

What is the nature of the relationship between 4SID and 4DVAR/EnKF?

I can't make myself believe that it is as simple as one is processed forward in time (4DVAR/EnKF) and one is processed backward in time (4SID).

Comment: Are you just looking for a yes or no answer?

Comment: @MichaelChernick - nope.  I would cry.  A paragraph and some references to decent material would be nice.

Comment: Now it does seem that you are looking for a different explanation. Can you give us some background on these methods so that someone might be better able to answer the question?

Comment: give me a day... the details section is going to be .. challenge/fun/tough